# Java:Three digit Sum - Find out all the numbers between 1 and 999 where the sum of 1st digit and 2nd digit is equal to 3rd digit

Tags: java

Problem statement: Three digit sum - Find all the numbers between 1 and 999 where the sum of the 1st digit and the 2nd digit is equal to the 3rd digit.

Examples:
<sub>123 : 1+2 = 3</sub>
<sup>246 : 2+4 = 6</sup>

Java:

```
public class AssignmentFive {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i=1;
    int valuetwo;
    int n=1;
    int sum = 0;
    int valuethree;
    int valueone = 0;
    String Numbers = "";
   for (i = 1; i <= 999; i++) {
        n = i;
        while (n > 1) {
            valueone = n % 10;/*To get the ones place digit*/
            n = n / 10;
            valuetwo = n % 10;/*To get the tens place digit*/
            n = n / 10;
            valuethree = n;/*To get the hundreds place digit*/
            sum = valuethree + valuetwo;/*adding the hundreds place and 
       tens place*/

        }
  /*Checking if the ones place digit is equal to the sum and then print 
      the values in a string format*/
        if (sum == valueone) {
            Numbers = Numbers + n + " ";
            System.out.println(Numbers);
        }
    }

    }
}
```

I got my result :

```
1
10
100
1000
10000
100000
1000000
10000000
100000000
1000000000
10000000001
100000000011
1000000000111
10000000001111
100000000011111
1000000000111111
10000000001111111
100000000011111111
1000000000111111111

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The result is not showing the actual result like it should be which should show values like: 123, 246 (Please refer to the problem statement above.)

Please let me know what seems to be the issue with the code and how to tweak it.

Comment: Sorry I can't follow your logic. What are you trying to do? Pls comment your code.  Note, the first number satisfying the condition is perhaps `11` (or `011`) but I don't know that's intended as it isn't really a `3 digit` number usually.  So really it's `101` and next `112` and `123` etc. up to `189` before going to `202` and `213` etc.  Why not convert to string, use string manipulation to get each digit and convert them back to the individual numbers for doing the arithmetic check?  Hth,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what you're trying to do with that `while` loop, or why you are building up a space-separated string of numbers.

Your code should be something like:

```
for (int n = 1; n <= 999; n++) {
   int digit1 = // for you to write code here
   int digit2 = // for you to write code here
   int digit3 = // for you to write code here
   if (digit1 + digit2 == digit3) {
       // print n here
   }
}
```

Comment: Be careful! There are two and 3 digit numvers. I guess using modulo will work and return 0 but still a thing to think about.

Comment: @F_Schmidt Since the assignment/challenge says *"numbers between 1 and 999"*, not *"numbers between 100 and 999"*, it obviously considers numbers between 1 and 99 to be 3-digit numbers too, making `11` aka `011` such a number (0+1 = 1). --- Of course, if the solution is rejected, it's simple enough to change the loop to start at 100, and is really beyond the point of this question.

Comment: Yes I know and you are completly right ;) Just wanted to clarify.

Comment: @Andreas Got it. It was a silly mistake. I have changed the code to take only three digit numbers and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

So basically your question is how to calculate the numbers, right?

My first hint for you would be how to get the first, second and third value from a 2 or 3 digit number.

For example for 3 digits you can do `int hundretDigit = (n - (n % 100)) % 100`. Of course this is really inefficient. But just get code working before optimizing it ;)

Just think about a way to get the "ten-digit" (2nd number). Then you add them and if they equal the third one you write `System.out.println(<number>);`

EDIT:
For 2 digit numbers I will give you the code:

```
if(i >= 10 && i <= 99) {
    int leftDigit = (i - (i % 10)) / 10;
    if(leftDigit == (i % 10)) {
        //Left digit equals right digit (for example 33 => 3 = 3
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Try again and edit your source code. If you have more questions I will edit my (this) answer to give you a little bit more help if you need!